# Assume $g$ is a convex function. Is it true that $g(E[X], E[Y]) \leq E[g(X,Y)]$ if $X$ and $Y$ are discrete random variables.

Tags: probability

Assume $g$ is a convex function. If $X$ and $Y$ are discrete random variables, is it true that $g(E[X], E[Y]) \leq E[g(X,Y)]$? Is it the same as Jensen's inequality? Here we have two variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, assuming $g$ is jointly convex (as opposed to component-wise convex, which is a weaker notion), and is due to Jensen's inequality.

[Proof sketch: by convexity, there exists an affine function $h(x,y)$ such that $h(x,y) \le g(x,y)$ for all $x,y$, with $h(E[X], E[Y])=g(E[X], E[Y])$. Thus $h(X,Y) \le g(X,Y)$ almost surely, and taking expectations of both sides and using the fact that $h$ is affine yields $g(E[X], E[Y]) = h(E[X], E[Y]) = E[h(X,Y)] \le E[g(X,Y)]$.]

Comment: (+1) Nice rendition of the main idea of Jensen's inequality. A bit of nitpicking is that $h$ is in general an [affine transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation).

Comment: @SangchulLee Thanks for the correction!